# Warning when saving variables in tensorflow 1.1.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm in the process of upgrading from tensorflow version 0.12 to version 1.1 and I'm getting a warning that I don't understand when I save my trained variables.  I'm running python 3.5.2 on Windows.  Tensorflow was installed through pip and I'm only running on CPU.

I'm able to reproduce the warning with the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
import numpy as np

batch_size = 1
timesteps = 1
rnn_size = 4
n_channels = 1

with tf.Graph().as_default():


    input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, timesteps, n_channels])

    with tf.name_scope('connected_input'):
        input_w = tf.get_variable('connected_w', [n_channels, rnn_size], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed=1), dtype=tf.float32)
        input_b = tf.get_variable('connected_b', [rnn_size], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0), dtype=tf.float32)

    inputs = tf.nn.relu(tf.einsum('ijk,kl->ijl', input_data, input_w) + input_b)
    inputs = tf.unstack(inputs, num=timesteps, axis=1)

    lstm_cell = rnn.LSTMCell(4, state_is_tuple=True, initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed=1))
    cell = rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell] * 1, state_is_tuple=True)

    initial_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

    outputs, state = rnn.static_rnn(cell, inputs, initial_state=initial_state, scope='RNN')


    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=4)) as sess:
         tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

        outputs_val, state_val = sess.run([outputs, state], {input_data:np.reshape(np.array(0), [1,1,1])})

        saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=tf.trainable_variables())        
        saver.save(sess, save_path='c:/tf_vars.dat')
```

This yields the following warning:

`WARNING:tensorflow:Error encountered when serializing LAYER_NAME_UIDS.
Type is unsupported, or the types of the items don't match field type in CollectionDef.
'dict' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: Did you paste the complete code ? I am not able to reproduce the error in TF 1.1

Comment: @hars yes this code is complete in that it produces the warning message for me.  Could it be platform-specific?  I'm running on python 3.5.2 windows without GPU support...

Comment: may be. it's working pretty fine with Ubuntu, TF1.1, Py 2.7